# The specified URL cannot be found

Tags: 7, debugging

My site was working absolutely fine but suddenly I got an error:

> The specified URL cannot be found.

Whenever I click on submit button of any form on site (custom/admin, eg: while saving node, while updating user info) browser displays the above error. I found in console, for POST request it shows `404:Page not found` error.

I thought server might be blocking POST requests. So I created in test.php file containing simple form and `method=POST`.  It works fine.  This means there is some problem with my Drupal instance.

I used `ddebug_backtrace()` for debugging purpose but it is giving me empty response.

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: _This means there is some problem with my Drupal instance_ Probably not - more likely to be your server configuration. Make sure URL rewriting is working correctly as a first step

Comment: How does the base URL of your website looks like? Can you compate the URL of the originating page with the form action's URL that is reported as not found? I am thinking if that could be a subfolder/rewrite problem. Cheers

Comment: @StefanosPetrakis,  Considering node save example, both URLs are same.
1. Node edit URL : www.example.com/node/830/edit
2. Form action URL, reported as 404 : www.example.com/node/830/edit

Comment: @Clive, My first opinion was the same as yours but if the problem persists from server end,  it should not work for my simple form written in test.php file. I am bit confused.

Comment: Unless the URL for your test PHP file is also rewritten, that's irrelevant. Just search Google for "drupal 404 post save". The first 4/5 results (for me anyway) all say the same thing: problems with clean URLs. It's quite common. Use Postman or similar to send a `GET` request to that URL, and then a `POST` to the same. The GET will work, the POST won't, which pretty much confirms it

Comment: I second the comment(s) from Clive. A probably easy way to isolate this, is to disable the "Clean URLs" (/admin/config/search/clean-urls) and see if the problem persists.

Comment: This problem was due to server. System admin team had blocked the post requests.